# Execute Custom method in class using an Intent android

Tags: android, service, android-intent, callback

I want to call a custom method in a class which can be passed in Intent. In the receiver side of Intent, I want to call my custom method of the class. Lets say I have a class extends ResultReceiver which two methods

```
class MyClass extends ResultReceiver {

    public doBefore(){ //custom method
        Log.d("sdf","before");
    }

    public doAfter(){  // custom method
        Log.d("sdf","After");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveResult(final int resultCode,   final Bundle resultData) {

    }
}
```

I want to pass the MyClass in the Intent to another Activity or Service. So Lets say i am passing the MyClass to a service

```
MyClass mcl = new MyClass()
final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_RECEIVER, mcl);
```

In  MyService class, I get the intent in onHandleIntent() method.

Method in MyService Class

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    MyClass eval = (MyClass) intent.getParcelableExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_RECEIVER);
    eval.doBefore(); // Is this possible??
    eval.doAfter(); 
    sendSuccess(intent, null);
}
```

Now I want to execute the two methods in the of the class "MyClass". onReceiveResult() in the "MyClass" is called at the end but I am not able to call my custom method.  I dont want to start an activity or service. I want to my custom method to be executed.

Is there anyway I can call my custom method from the Service or Activity like ResultReceiver's onReceiveResult().??

Comment: You add your own method to a class which extends ResultReceiver. Because the class which extends the ResultReceiver are used  like a callback, from my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question properly, because it seem confusing that you try to access through your intent calls. Would it not be possible to simply do like below?

```
mcl.doBefore();
```

Comment: It is not possible to call a method in the receiver side of the intent. You pass a object in an intent from A to B. In B, you access the intent Extras. My question is how to call the objects method in B.

Comment: @Madjokr, yes I see your point, and I am aware of how to call the intent itself. I was just thinking whether you need it to wrap your call through the intent, would it not be possible to make a direct call? Else, it may be better to invoke your methods from the intent start method, then you do not worry about interfacing at all and future name changes. :-)

Comment: Can you please give me some example.?  I didnt get your point.